# CUDALink: Launching multiple blocks in z-dimension

Tags: 3d, cuda, wolfram-mathematica, stencils

Im currently running a simple 3D stencil transformation on my GPU (GTX560Ti) using the `CUDALink` wrapper provided by Mathematica. Block dimensions don't really matter to me right now, because I'm not using any shared memory or looking for optimization (right now).

Thus I can set any reasonable number for `blockDim.x` and `blockDim.y`. The wrapper will launch the appropriate amount of blocks no matter what dimension I set, no problem. However in the z-dimension only a single block is launched. Thus `blockDim.z` limits the total amount of points I can calculate in that direction.

**Why is there only one block in z-direction? How can I work around that?**

For reference, here is the kernel I'm using:

```
__global__ void conv(Real_t in[48][48][48], Real_t out[48][48][48], mint stencil[13][13][13], mint length, mint rad) {
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    int z = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z*blockDim.z;
    while (x<length||y<length||z<length) {
        out[x][y][z] = 0;
        for (int ix = -rad; ix <= rad; ix++) {
        for (int iy = -rad; iy <= rad; iy++) {
        for (int iz = -rad; iz <= rad; iz++) {
            if ( (fminf(x,fminf(y,z))-rad >= 0)
                && (fmaxf(x,fmaxf(y,z))+rad < length) )
                {out[x][y][z] += stencil[ix+rad][iy+rad][iz+rad]*in[ix+x][iy+y][iz+z];}
        }   }   }
        if (x<length) {
            x+= blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
        } else if (y<length) {
            y+= blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
        } else if (z<length) {
            z+= blockDim.z * gridDim.z;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note: The variable `length` corresponds to the dimensions of the arrays (eg 48). `rad` is related to the stencil and smaller than `length`. `stencil` is just an array of 0s and 1s to select the stuff from `in` I want to sum up into `out`.

I'm running the kernel in Mathematica using the following code:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"];
conv = CUDAFunctionLoad[code (*the kernel above, stored as a string*), "conv", {{_Real, _, "Input"}, {_Real, _, "Output"}, {_Integer , _, "Input"}, _Integer, _Integer}, {4, 4, 10}, "TargetPrecision" -> "Single", "XCompilerInstallation" -> "/usr/local/gcc44/bin/", "CleanIntermediate" -> False];
output = ConstantArray[1, {length, length, length}];
result =  conv[input, output, stencil, length, rad];
```

To illustrate my problem, here is a slice of my output (apparently I cant post images):

```
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.000578704 0.00173611  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.000289352 0.000868056 0.00173611  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.000578704 0.00144676  0.00260417  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.00115741  0.00202546  0.00347222  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.00115741  0.00202546  0.00347222  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.000578704 0.00144676  0.00289352  1.  1.  1.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.000578704 0.00144676  0.00289352  1.  1.  1.
```

This was produced with `blockDim.z = 10`. The zeroes and fractions are useful values, but the ones are just the values I initialized the `out` array with. Only the first 10 columns are computed, corresponding to a single block in z-direction. ( This behaviour is reproducible for any value of `blockDim.z` between `1` and `64` (the upper limit for Fermi GPUs).

Comment: auto compilation in CUDALink is [conditioned on the currently selected GPU](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Programming.html).  Do you have any other GPUs in your system besides the GTX 560 Ti ?  A cc 1.x device would be [limited to one block in the grid Z-dimension](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications).

Comment: No. `$ lspci` only lists the 560Ti, onboard graphics are disabled.

Comment: `CUDAInformation[]` is also quite clear: `Maximum Grid Dimensions->{65535,65535,65535}`. Writing `gridDim.z` into `out[x][y][z]` however fills the array with `1`. So the wrapper thinks one block is enough. Is it possible to override that? I would rather not rewrite my program in C...

Comment: Modify your `conv` invocation by adding an [extra set of parameters](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/cuda-setting-grid-dimensions) specifying the desired grid dimensions, in *threads*.  Something like: `result =  conv[input, output, stencil, length, rad, {48, 48, 48}];`

Comment: OK. That results in the following error: `CUDAFunction::invgrd: "CUDALink was called with invalid grid dimensions {48,48,48}. Grid dimensions must be positive and either an Integer or a list of Integers."`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I guess this behaviour was just a bug in CUDAResources and not an actual programming issue. (Still, there is only one block though. What I have now is a workaround.)

I removed CUDAResources with `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]` , restarted Mathematica, reinstalled using `CUDAResourcesInstall["/path/to/paclet/file",Update->True]` and restarted Mathematica again.

Then I changed my kernel to the following code:

```
__global__ void conv(Real_t in[48][48][48], Real_t out[48][48][48], \
mint stencil[13][13][13], mint length, mint rad) {
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    int z = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z*blockDim.z;
    while (z<length) {
        out[x][y][z] = 0;
        for (int ix = -rad; ix <= rad; ix++) {
        for (int iy = -rad; iy <= rad; iy++) {
        for (int iz = -rad; iz <= rad; iz++) {
            if ( (fminf(x,fminf(y,z))-rad >= 0)
                && (fmaxf(x,fmaxf(y,z))+rad < length) )
                {out[x][y][z] += stencil[ix+rad][iy+rad][iz+rad]*in[ix+x][iy+y][iz+z];}
        }   }   }
        if (z<length) {
            z+= blockDim.z * gridDim.z;
        }
    }
}
```

And now it works. Hopefully it stays that way. This of course means that there is less parallelisation going on in z-direction, because there is basically one block of threads going sequentially over the grid instead of multiple blocks doing work in parallel. But that's fine, the code is fast enough for my purposes.

Big thanks to everyone who helped.